# Can more than one user access the same Excel file at the same time without conflict?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub TryAgainPrint()
If ActiveCell.Column <> 5 Then
    MsgBox ("Select a cell in column Call ref. num.")
    Exit Sub
Else:
End If '
' TryAgainPrint Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:H1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Print").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Problems").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Range("A1:I1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Print").Select
    Range("A4:I4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Problems").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Print").Select
    Range("D6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the code has to do with the title? If you meant like in a shared drive, indeed you can, just the first person to open the document is the one allowed to save it.

Comment: Yes, several people can access the same Excel file at the same time. Just look at the `Review` tab in Excel and then click `Share Workbook`. Yet, could you please explain what you mean by "...without conflict"?

Comment: Here are a few limitations you will have to work with in "shared workbooks": https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61 And this might be useful too: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-49ec5cb7-0f7e-4781-be66-14ae173a7a29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple users opening Excel at the same time.  **If** you save it for sharing as a shared workbook.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your help, that answers my question.